# toggle through items in a text file using c

Tags: c, list

I have a list of primes in the form

```
p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7
p8  p9  p10 p11 p12 p13 p14
p15 p16 p17 p18 p19 p20 p21
....
```

I want to write a loop that select each of these in succession and then does something with them (multiply them with another one of the primes). I am not sure how to go about this; my code so far looks like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    FILE *fr;
    fr = fopen ("primes1.txt", "rt");  
}
```

So yeah I didn't really get far. I did something like this before but then the amount of data in the text file was very small.  The file I am using now contains one million primes. If anyone can help me out I will be very thankful!

Comment: The code you show does nothing useful. At least post the code you've done for small data file.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have elaborated on that. I meant the file was so small (had about 20 elements) that I could just enter it in the code directly without referring to any file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to read the numbers individually like so:

```
int n;
FILE *fp;

if ( (fp = fopen("foo.txt", "r")) == NULL )
{
    // Do something if the file's not found
    return -1;
}

while ( fscanf(fp, "%d", &n) == 1 )
{
    // fscanf reads the next integer and skip white space, including linefeeds
    // Do something with the next value "n" from the file
    // You can store them in an array, manipulate all the ones read so far, etc
}

fclose( fp );
```

Comment: Is there any way I can have it start at a certain position?

Comment: @Slugger, if you mean at a particular prime, then the easiest way is probably to just read them as above and skip/count the ones you don't want. Alternatively, you could read one byte at a time using `fgetc(fp)` and scan for and count separating "white space" sequences, which might be more efficient since you're not converting to integer each time. But it wouldn't be quite as "tidy" in the context of your code. Depending upon your application, that level of efficiency may not matter.